# php symfony 1.4: how to redirect with csrf token

Tags: php, redirect, symfony-1.4

i want to redirect from action `a` to action `b` in the same module. Action `b` requires csrf token to execute, and i need to pass it a few parameters as well.

action a:

```
public function executeA(sfWebRequest $request){

   //... do stuff

   $this->redirect('module/b?id='.$something->getId());

}
```

action b:

```
public function executeB(sfWebRequest $request){

   $request->checkCSRFProtection(); //morte

   $something_id = $request->getParameter('id');
   //... do stuff

}
```

the action `b` executes, only if clicked on anchor created by `link_to('module/b?id='.$something.getId() , array('method' => 'post'))` or any other method, because it sends csrf token with the request.

i tried `$this->forward()` and `$this->redirect()` methods, and tried to add `'method' => 'post'` to redirect params like in `link_to()` , but nothing works, and i cant find anything about it on the web either. API documentation says noting about it. all i get is

```
 500 | Internal Server Error | sfValidatorErrorSchema
_csrf_token [Required.]
```

error. it fails on the line marked `//morte`. please, does anyone know, how to do this properly, and also in cases that i want to redirect to other module?

Comment: `_csrf_token` is only used in form. Are you forwarding a form ?

Comment: `_csrf_token` is used in anchors with some methods as well. `url_for('module/action' , array('method' => 'post')` for example does it. check `html` of such an anchor. i use `$request->checkCSRFProtection()` in actions i don't want to be accesible simply by typing in url. to answer your question : no, i'm not forwarding a form. i just want the csrf protected action to trigger when done processing the form.

Comment: This is still unclear for me ..

Comment: i'll rewrite the question in more detail

Comment: i made an error in the comment and in the question as well : exchange `url_for()` with `link_to()`

Comment: I am not complettely shure but maybe you have to add requirements: { token: \w+ } to your route in routing.yml

Comment: wont that just add a requirement, and make a 500 error into 404?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok this more clear now.

The fact is the `_csrf_token` isn't redirect to the other action, I mean, you didn't re-add it in the query.

Try:

```
public function executeA(sfWebRequest $request){

   //... do stuff

   $this->redirect('module/b?id='.$something->getId().'?_csrf_token='.$request->getParameter('_csrf_token'));

}
```

Comment: is it possible to generate a token inside the controller, e.g. the `executeB` class?

Comment: Well, yes. You should create a fake sfForm and then call [`getCSRFToken()`](http://trac.symfony-project.org/browser/branches/1.4/lib/form/sfForm.class.php#L884). But why don't you generate a custom parameter, like ?nocsrf=1 in `execute1` and then, check that in `executeB` if `nosrf` is here, do not call `checkCSRFProtection` ?

Comment: wouldn't that beat the purpose? anyone who knew about that parameter working could bypass the CSRF protection check. i tried it with the fake form, but it doesn't work. `[CSRF attack detected.]` i don't know exactly how the `$this->checkCSRFProtection()` method works in symfony, but according to error report it does a `bind()` function on some sfForm, though i had not created any form in the controller part that checks it.

Comment: Have you tried the solution in my answer? The token is generated on the first request based on a secret code, the session id and the class that call the generation. Then, when submitting the request, it will check that the code match the same generation. Are `executeA` and `executeB` in the same controller?

Comment: i did, but `$request->getParameter('_csrf_token')` returned nothing, and using the token from form that gets processed returned the CSRF attack error.

Comment: Did you generate the token on `executeA` or in `executeB` ? Are `executeA` and `executeB` in the same controller?

Comment: Then I don't know ... You should dig into the `checkCSRFProtection`, put some var_dump and see when the csrf_token change, etc ..